# Wordpress e Laravel em mesmo servidor e mesmo dominio

Tags: laravel, wordpress, htaccess

Tenho um **Wordpress** configurado em uma pasta root no servidor e criei uma subpasta com um **Laravel**, o WP funciona normalmente, mas o Laravel abre só o index, quando tento abrir as rotas abre uma página de erro do WP, a estrutura está assim:

`/wordpress` -> abre o wp corretamente

`/wordpress/post-wp` -> abre a rota do wordpress corretamente

`/wordpress/laravel` -> abre a página inicial da aplicacao do laravel corretamente (diretorio onde está o laravel)

`/wordpress/laravel/rota` -> abre uma página de erro do wp

Segue meu htaccess do wordpress:

```
# BEGIN GzipWpFastestCache
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
AddType x-font/woff .woff
AddType x-font/ttf .ttf
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE x-font/ttf
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype font/ttf font/eot font/otf
</IfModule>
# END GzipWpFastestCache
# BEGIN LBCWpFastestCache
<FilesMatch "\.(webm|ogg|mp4|ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|webp|js|css|swf|x-html|css|xml|js|woff|woff2|otf|ttf|svg|eot)(\.gz)?$">
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
AddType application/font-woff2 .woff2
AddType application/x-font-opentype .otf
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault A0
ExpiresByType video/webm A10368000
ExpiresByType video/ogg A10368000
ExpiresByType video/mp4 A10368000
ExpiresByType image/webp A10368000
ExpiresByType image/gif A10368000
ExpiresByType image/png A10368000
ExpiresByType image/jpg A10368000
ExpiresByType image/jpeg A10368000
ExpiresByType image/ico A10368000
ExpiresByType image/svg+xml A10368000
ExpiresByType text/css A10368000
ExpiresByType text/javascript A10368000
ExpiresByType application/javascript A10368000
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript A10368000
ExpiresByType application/font-woff2 A10368000
ExpiresByType application/x-font-opentype A10368000
ExpiresByType application/x-font-truetype A10368000
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Expires "max-age=A10368000, public"
Header unset ETag
Header set Connection keep-alive
FileETag None
</IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
# END LBCWpFastestCache

# BEGIN WPLetsEncrypt
# As diretrizes (linhas) entre `BEGIN WPLetsEncrypt` e` END WPLetsEncrypt` são
# geradas dinamicamente e só devem ser modificadas através de filtros do WordPress.
# Quaisquer alterações nas diretivas entre esses marcadores serão sobrescritas.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^.well-known/acme-challenge/(.*)$ $1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
# END WPLetsEncrypt
```

E o htacces do laravel na pasta public:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Como posso solucionar esse problema ?

Answer (score 3):

Talvez colocar o `RewriteBase` no arquivo `.htaccess` na pasta laravel possa resolver. Ficaria desta forma:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteBase /laravel/

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```